# Sql insert c# windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, windows, forms, winforms

I am working on a windows form project with a sql database I want to write some data but I couldn't. (the code doesn't give any error however no data is written.
The code below is the place where I want to write the data:

```
 public static string stringConnection = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\POS.mdf; Integrated Security=True";
                    try
                    {
                        mySql = string.Empty;
                        mySql += "INSERT INTO Journal (Date) VALUES (" + "'"+ caisse + "'"+")" ;
                        connection.exsql(mySql);
                    }
                    catch(Exception exx)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exx.ToString());
                    }
```

and here is the connection.exsql method:

```
public static void exsql(string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = default(SqlDataAdapter);
        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = stringConnection;
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            connection.Close();
            //connection = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal sql error: " + ex.Message, "Sql Server connection failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not executing any commands, you are just opening a connection and creating an adapter, but doing nothing with it. Research `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Also this is a very old way of dealing with data in .NET applications. The approach nowadays is to use Entity Framework, though it's more code but better in the long run.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Your `exsql` method doesn't provide for that.

Comment: @MatthewLayton That statement is very incomplete. You shouldn't just tell an info like that to new programmer, they will think it's the best thing in the whole world. The reality is that it's not just more code, it's a massive hit on data performance in all cases i have seen. We have been converting couple dozen business apps every year that run on EF over plain SQL services and had gain of more than 10x speed. Maybe on paper it look good but reality is telling me otherwise for the last 8 years we have been converting those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `sqlCommand` and execute `.ExecuteNonQuery()` to do an INSERT or UPDATE.

More info [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient).

Also, use parameterization (an example is shown in the link above), otherwise, you open yourself up to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and your code will fail if your variable contains a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    public bool exsql(string query)
    {       
       try {
            con = null;
            con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.path);
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            var rowEffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if(rowEffected>0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception occurred !", 
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
           MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }
    }
```

You can execute your query by ExecuteNonQuery() function

Comment: This is valid code; however, one issue you can run into, if var rowEffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); fails, con.Close() is never called.  Do this enough times (>100) you will run out of available connections.  Wrapping using around the code will mitigate that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Less code

```
    private bool exsql(string query)
    { 
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.path))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) 
                return command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0 ? false : true;  
        }
    }
```